# Calling public state variable is giving error

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, dapps

I have a public state variable which holds a payable address. I want to get its value by ethers.js. When I call `contract.variableName()` it is returning `contract.variableName is not a function` error. What wrong i am doing? It was in `async` function and i used `await contract.variableName()`.

Comment: are you loading the contact correctly? are u sure that the contract is deployed and u are using the correct address?

Comment: Everything is okay

Comment: can you try to get the value on remix ide?